# distance function $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}d(x)|= 1$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a nonempty compact set, and

$\displaystyle d(x)=d(x,K)= \inf_{y\in K}|x-y|$.

It holds that $|d(x)-d(y)| \leq|x-y|$, so

$d$ is differentiable almost every where, and  $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}d(x)|\leq 1 \ a.e. x \in \mathbb{R^d}$.

Does it hold $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}d(x)|= 1 \ a.e. x \in K^c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general you have that $|\nabla d(x)| = 1$ at any point of differentiability of $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus K$ (hence a.e.).

More precisely, if $x\in \mathbb{R^d}\setminus K$ and $y\in K$ is a projection of $x$ on $K$, then $d$ is differentiable along the segment
$$
]x,y[ := \{tx + (1-t)y:\ t\in (0,1)\}
$$
and
$$
\nabla d(z) = \frac{x-y}{|x-y|}
\qquad \forall z\in ]x,y[.
$$

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: See e.g. the book of Cannarsa and Sinestrari, "Semiconcave functions...", Corollary 3.4.5.